# Rails/ActiveAdmin association error - No route matches … missing required keys: [:category_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm really new to Rails and have hit an issue where I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain what I've done wrong simply. Having looked at quite a few questions on here that are similar I can't quite identify which part of the process my error is occurring in.

I had a pretty basic site that was working absolutely fine, and I added ActiveAdmin. All good. At that point I decided to introduce a relationship in the form of categories. Previously, a user could have multiple statuses. After the change:

- a user could have multiple statuses
- a status would belong to one category
- a category can be associated with many statuses
- categories can be managed through the admin panel
- categories cannot be managed directly through the public site

This is where I've broken something. The public side of the site still allows me to do CRUD operations on statuses absolutely fine. However I now can't access *any* of the ActiveAdmin pages because of the error, which was only introduced after I tried to relate statuses to categories.

If anyone can point me in the direction of the problem, or provide any additional reading it would be hugely appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**Full error**

http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin returns

```
Showing /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-3941e1550c4d/app/views/active_admin/page/index.html.arb where line #2 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/statuses"} missing required keys: [:category_id]
Extracted source (around line #2):
insert_tag active_admin_application.view_factory["page"]
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170107060018) do

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "namespace"
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "resource_id",   null: false
    t.string   "resource_type", null: false
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.string   "author_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id"
  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace"
  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id"

  create_table "admin_users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "admin_users", ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "admin_users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string "cat_name", null: false
  end

  create_table "statuses", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "private",     default: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  add_index "statuses", ["category_id"], name: "index_statuses_on_category_id"
  add_index "statuses", ["user_id"], name: "index_statuses_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "profile_name"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  get '/dashboard', to: 'profiles#dashboard', as: :dashboard

  get 'profiles/show'

  get '/home', to: 'pages#home', as: :homepage
  get '/about', to: 'pages#about', as: :aboutpage
  get '/credits', to: 'pages#credits', as: :creditspage

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations"}

  devise_scope :user do
    get 'register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register
    get 'login', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :login
    get 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
  end 

  resources :statuses

  get 'feed', to: 'statuses#index', as: :feed
  root to: 'pages#home' #Nothing in the path - index

  get '/:id', to: 'profiles#show'
end
```

**Models**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :statuses
end

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category

    validates :content, presence: true, length: {minimum: 2}
    validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

**Controllers**
**statuses_controller.rb**

```
class StatusesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  before_action :set_status, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:destroy, :edit]

  def index
    @statuses = Status.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50).order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def show
    if can? :read, @status
      render action: :show
    else
      render file: 'public/pleaseregister'
    end
  end

  def new
    @status = Status.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @status = @user.statuses.build(status_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.save
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @status }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    if can? :update, @status
    respond_to do |format|

        if @status.update(status_params)

          format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @status }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end

    end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if can? :delete, @status
      @status.destroy
      respond_to do |format|

          format.html { redirect_to statuses_url, notice: 'Status was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
  end


  private
    def set_status
      @status = Status.find(params[:id])
    end

    def status_params
      params.require(:status).permit(:name, :content, :user_id, :private, :category_id)
    end

    def correct_user
      @status = current_user.statuses.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @status.nil?
    end
end
```

**categories_controller.rb**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

end
```

**rake routes**

```
Prefix Verb       URI Pattern                                                    Controller#Action
              new_admin_user_session GET        /admin/login(.:format)                                         active_admin/devise/sessions#new
                  admin_user_session POST       /admin/login(.:format)                                         active_admin/devise/sessions#create
          destroy_admin_user_session DELETE|GET /admin/logout(.:format)                                        active_admin/devise/sessions#destroy
                 admin_user_password POST       /admin/password(.:format)                                      active_admin/devise/passwords#create
             new_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/new(.:format)                                  active_admin/devise/passwords#new
            edit_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/edit(.:format)                                 active_admin/devise/passwords#edit
                                     PATCH      /admin/password(.:format)                                      active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                                     PUT        /admin/password(.:format)                                      active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                          admin_root GET        /admin(.:format)                                               admin/dashboard#index
      batch_action_admin_admin_users POST       /admin/admin_users/batch_action(.:format)                      admin/admin_users#batch_action
                   admin_admin_users GET        /admin/admin_users(.:format)                                   admin/admin_users#index
                                     POST       /admin/admin_users(.:format)                                   admin/admin_users#create
                new_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/new(.:format)                               admin/admin_users#new
               edit_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id/edit(.:format)                          admin/admin_users#edit
                    admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)                               admin/admin_users#show
                                     PATCH      /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)                               admin/admin_users#update
                                     PUT        /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)                               admin/admin_users#update
                                     DELETE     /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)                               admin/admin_users#destroy
       batch_action_admin_categories POST       /admin/categories/batch_action(.:format)                       admin/categories#batch_action
                    admin_categories GET        /admin/categories(.:format)                                    admin/categories#index
                                     POST       /admin/categories(.:format)                                    admin/categories#create
                  new_admin_category GET        /admin/categories/new(.:format)                                admin/categories#new
                 edit_admin_category GET        /admin/categories/:id/edit(.:format)                           admin/categories#edit
                      admin_category GET        /admin/categories/:id(.:format)                                admin/categories#show
                                     PATCH      /admin/categories/:id(.:format)                                admin/categories#update
                                     PUT        /admin/categories/:id(.:format)                                admin/categories#update
                                     DELETE     /admin/categories/:id(.:format)                                admin/categories#destroy
                     admin_dashboard GET        /admin/dashboard(.:format)                                     admin/dashboard#index
batch_action_admin_category_statuses POST       /admin/categories/:category_id/statuses/batch_action(.:format) admin/statuses#batch_action
             admin_category_statuses GET        /admin/categories/:category_id/statuses(.:format)              admin/statuses#index
                                     POST       /admin/categories/:category_id/statuses(.:format)              admin/statuses#create
           new_admin_category_status GET        /admin/categories/:category_id/statuses/new(.:format)          admin/statuses#new
          edit_admin_category_status GET        /admin/categories/:category_id/statuses/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/statuses#edit
               admin_category_status GET        /admin/categories/:category_id/statuses/:id(.:format)          admin/statuses#show
                                     PATCH      /admin/categories/:category_id/statuses/:id(.:format)          admin/statuses#update
                                     PUT        /admin/categories/:category_id/statuses/:id(.:format)          admin/statuses#update
                                     DELETE     /admin/categories/:category_id/statuses/:id(.:format)          admin/statuses#destroy
            batch_action_admin_users POST       /admin/users/batch_action(.:format)                            admin/users#batch_action
                         admin_users GET        /admin/users(.:format)                                         admin/users#index
                                     POST       /admin/users(.:format)                                         admin/users#create
                      new_admin_user GET        /admin/users/new(.:format)                                     admin/users#new
                     edit_admin_user GET        /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format)                                admin/users#edit
                          admin_user GET        /admin/users/:id(.:format)                                     admin/users#show
                                     PATCH      /admin/users/:id(.:format)                                     admin/users#update
                                     PUT        /admin/users/:id(.:format)                                     admin/users#update
                                     DELETE     /admin/users/:id(.:format)                                     admin/users#destroy
                      admin_comments GET        /admin/comments(.:format)                                      admin/comments#index
                                     POST       /admin/comments(.:format)                                      admin/comments#create
                       admin_comment GET        /admin/comments/:id(.:format)                                  admin/comments#show
                                     DELETE     /admin/comments/:id(.:format)                                  admin/comments#destroy
                           dashboard GET        /dashboard(.:format)                                           profiles#dashboard
                       profiles_show GET        /profiles/show(.:format)                                       profiles#show
                            homepage GET        /home(.:format)                                                pages#home
                           aboutpage GET        /about(.:format)                                               pages#about
                         creditspage GET        /credits(.:format)                                             pages#credits
                    new_user_session GET        /users/sign_in(.:format)                                       devise/sessions#new
                        user_session POST       /users/sign_in(.:format)                                       devise/sessions#create
                destroy_user_session DELETE     /users/sign_out(.:format)                                      devise/sessions#destroy
                       user_password POST       /users/password(.:format)                                      devise/passwords#create
                   new_user_password GET        /users/password/new(.:format)                                  devise/passwords#new
                  edit_user_password GET        /users/password/edit(.:format)                                 devise/passwords#edit
                                     PATCH      /users/password(.:format)                                      devise/passwords#update
                                     PUT        /users/password(.:format)                                      devise/passwords#update
            cancel_user_registration GET        /users/cancel(.:format)                                        users/registrations#cancel
                   user_registration POST       /users(.:format)                                               users/registrations#create
               new_user_registration GET        /users/sign_up(.:format)                                       users/registrations#new
              edit_user_registration GET        /users/edit(.:format)                                          users/registrations#edit
                                     PATCH      /users(.:format)                                               users/registrations#update
                                     PUT        /users(.:format)                                               users/registrations#update
                                     DELETE     /users(.:format)                                               users/registrations#destroy
                            register GET        /register(.:format)                                            devise/registrations#new
                               login GET        /login(.:format)                                               devise/sessions#new
                              logout GET        /logout(.:format)                                              devise/sessions#destroy
                            statuses GET        /statuses(.:format)                                            statuses#index
                                     POST       /statuses(.:format)                                            statuses#create
                          new_status GET        /statuses/new(.:format)                                        statuses#new
                         edit_status GET        /statuses/:id/edit(.:format)                                   statuses#edit
                              status GET        /statuses/:id(.:format)                                        statuses#show
                                     PATCH      /statuses/:id(.:format)                                        statuses#update
                                     PUT        /statuses/:id(.:format)                                        statuses#update
                                     DELETE     /statuses/:id(.:format)                                        statuses#destroy
                                feed GET        /feed(.:format)                                                statuses#index
                                root GET        /                                                              pages#home
                                     GET        /:id(.:format)                                                 profiles#show
```

**app/admin/status.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Status do

    permit_params :user_id, :content, :private, :category_id
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    menu priority: 4

end
```

**app/admin/category.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do

    permit_params :cat_name
    has_many :statuses
    menu priority: 5

end
```

Comment: Please, post the `rake routes` output

Comment: @BMxer Thanks for the heads up - added now.

Comment: It seems the routing is resolving to `admin_category_statuses GET        /admin/categories/:category_id/statuses(.:format)              admin/statuses#index` and the `category_id` is missing, which corresponds to the error message. But I don't understand why accessing **:3000/admin** you get into that route.

Comment: IF you remove this line: "belongs_to :category" in Status.rb does it fix your error?

Comment: @ruby_newbie Afraid not, no change.

Comment: @Bmxer This is something to go on, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably somewhere in `app/views/active_admin/page/index.html.arb` (maybe you have a menu there?) you are building a link to /admin/statuses pages (`admin_category_statuses_path`), but you don't provide category parameter in there.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! The issue was within the rb files in the admin directory - I had wrongly tried to define a relationship between Category and Status here, and I think that was because I'd misunderstood the reference: http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html @ruby_newbie you were close, just wrong file but it made me look at this again :)

The relationship still isn't quite right within ActiveAdmin (filters are showing a reference to the objects rather than a name etc), but it's loading again and I shall go from here.

Thank you so much for all of your suggestions